# "Edit with IDLE" option missing from context menu

Tags: python, contextmenu, edit, python-idle

I have Python 2.7.5 that installed with ArcGIS 10.2.2.  When I first right-clicked a .py script I'd previously written it listed the "Edit with IDLE" option in the context menu.  However, this option no longer appears when I right-click a .py file.

I have read numerous threads concerning this issue and attempted some of them, such as modifying/removing registry keys and then reinstalling/repairing the software.  I am not interested in using an IDE at this point, though many will be happy to know I intend to use an IDE later on.  Right now, the purpose is to fix the problem rather than avoid and work around it.

I appreciate the help I've gotten from the online community in the past, and I'm confident someone will come through with a solution for me.

How do I get "Edit with IDLE" back in the context menu?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Directly from: https://superuser.com/questions/343519/python-idle-disappeared-from-the-right-click-context-menu

Here's a reg file to add the command to edit with IDLE for Python.File (.py) and Python.NoConFile (.pyw) file types. It's for Python 2.7, installed in C:\Python27, so substitute the paths to pythonw.exe and idle.pyw that are relevant to your installation. Save it to a .reg file. Then right-click and choose Merge.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Edit with IDLE\command]
@="\"C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe\" \"C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib\\idle.pyw\" -e \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\shell\Edit with IDLE\command]
@="\"C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe\" \"C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib\\idle.pyw\" -e \"%1\""
```

Comment: In my case this some how dosent work. Maybe because i got ArcGIS installed? But it worked after changing the same commands in the other path [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pyfile\shell\Edit with IDLE\command]

Answer (score 34):

Most of the time when this problem occurs, people will read answers directing them into the windows registry, often unnecessarily.

In the majority of cases, the registry key

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Edit with IDLE\command
```

will already exist and have the correct value, but it will only be used by Windows shell context menu if .py files are set by default to open with python.exe.

This is the first thing to check, and solves the problem in the majority of cases:

- right click on a .py file
- open with...
- choose default program...
- tick always use the selected program to open this kind of file
- choose python.exe

This runs the script in a terminal, but also sets the filetype back to python.

Now check the right click menu again.

Comment: This definitely worked for me.  Checked the Registry keys mentioned in Teodorico Levoff's answer and slightly different ones already existed for Python 3.5.  However, there was no default program set up for *.py files.  Once the default program was set the Edit with IDLE context menu appeared.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was at my wit's end trying to figure out why it wasn't working and not even reinstalling helped.

Comment: Can anybody help me? I have Python 3(7, 8 and 9) installed, and all their three IDLEs used to appear in the `Edit with IDLE` (and they are in the registries). I did the steps above and reset which app opens the file by default (3.7 `python.exe` file cause was the first one that I installed), but that didn't work for me, unfortunately. I saw that the `.exe` that opens `.py` files in the registry is the `pythonw.exe`, WHY???. Is it correct? What can be wrong? I faced the exact same problem as many of you: the "Edit with IDLE" disappeared from the windows context menu after a while. What do I do?

Comment: @NickS1 I'm sorry I don't use IDLE any more so I am not going to be able to help you

Comment: @Mark Ch, don't worry at all! Thank you so much for trying to help anyway! I appreciate it. At least, I can still open it with IDLE with not problems, so it's ok. Thanks for being willing to help!

Comment: Wow! Such an easy fix! To be completely honest, I was getting very irritated that the Python icon was not next to the files and, even though I don't use IDLE, I was annoyed that the option was missing. Instantly smiled when I saw the icon pop up. Many thanks.

Answer (score 24):

As a newer update, for people that are having the "missing idle" issue with Windows 10 using Python 3.6 (64-bit).

From my experience, this happens when you install other python editors, and you change your default app to open with that editor.

The easiest way to fix this issue is to click the "start" button, then navigate to settings --> System --> Default Apps --> "Choose default apps by file type". Scroll down till you find ".py" file type and click on the icon and choose "Python"(has a little rocket ship in the icon). This will change your default app back to "Python.exe", and the context menu "edit with idle" will appear once again on your ".py" files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This totally fixed by problem, no need registry changes after all. It's important to pick the Python icon with the rocket icon.

Comment: I also noticed that the install location of the Python default app with the rocket icon is located in C:\Windows\py.exe, which is why I couldn't find it (different from the IDLE install folder or python.exe).

Comment: This totally helped! Thanks a lot! Without any difficulty, I was able to do this!!

Comment: I don't get to choose Python with rocket icon in that menu: [image](https://prnt.sc/U7KGMA9n7Lhc)

Comment: @sortai I uninstalled Python, removed any leftovers and freshly installed again

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to just open the file with the idle by choosing open with:

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat
```

as the default program.

Comment: This is not recommended because the ProgId will be changed. This might be one of the reasons they dont have "Edit with IDLE" option. https://bugs.python.org/issue29014

Answer (score 3):

I got the `"Edit with IDLE"` back with the option `"Repair"` of the deinstallation-menu.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a little more detail to Teodorico Levoff's answer for those who need a little more explanation, like myself.

Open a text editor, such as Notepad, and copy/paste the following, but be sure to modify the paths to pythonw.exe and idle.pyw so that they match the paths in your own system:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Edit with IDLE\command]
@="\"C:\Python27\pythonw.exe\" \"C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw\" -e \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\shell\Edit with IDLE\command]
@="\"C:\Python27\pythonw.exe\" \"C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw\" -e \"%1\""
```

Save this text file as idle.reg in the Python27 folder, so you now have a file that resembles this (with your own file path, of course):

```
C:\Python27\idle.reg
```

Right-click the idle.reg file, and in the context menu, click Merge.  A couple instructions may appear or notices that require a Yes or Continue that I selected.  In the end, my .py files give me the option to "Edit in IDLE" again.

I hope these explanations are helpful.  Big thank you to those who've solved this problem before and shared there solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For opening your file in IDLE mode or in python exe mode u can follow this simple steps. Works for me in my windows 7 system.
For IDLE mode:

1. Select the file and press right mouse
2. press open with---->choose default program
3. press browse and go to the folder where your python programm is installed
4. in python folder search IDLE and select the batch file
5. press open and your file will be open in IDLE edit mode

For python.exe mode:

1. In command prompt write "where python"
2. copy the path from cmd
3. Select the file and press right mouse
4. press open with---->choose default program
5. press browse and go to the selected path
6. press open and your file will be open in IDLE edit mode

Comment: useful if python was installed through Windows app store

Answer (score 0):

As click to save button to save your python code there will be `Two Extensions`...1) `.py` and 2) `.pyw`.

So for Python 2 you have to save python program using extension `.pyw`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the majority of cases are caused by the Py launcher that comes with Python 3. When you install Python 3 alongside Python 2.x, the *.py and *.pyw files are associated to run with the new Py launcher. Since *.py and *.pyw files are no longer associated with Python.exe, that breaks the "Edit with IDLE" and similar context menu options, despite all relevant registry entries being present and correct.

Right clicking a file and choosing Python.exe and selecting "always use the selected program to open this kind of file" option fixes the problem (even if Python.exe seems to be already set as the default program) but then you lose the Py launcher functionality. This may well be considered a bug with the Python 3.x installer and I think should be fixed at that level by the Python developers.

Meanwhile, I'm sure registry wizards can find a workaround for this but unfortunately, that's beyond me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I followed Teodorico Levoff's directions above, as well as Abyx's from the following page:
https://superuser.com/questions/280636/trying-to-edit-a-python-file-but-the-edit-with-idle-has-disappeared-when-i-rig

However, it only works partially.  When I right-click on a .py file, no 'Edit with IDLE' shows up.  Choosing 'Edit' opens the file with IDLE.  Also, the python icon is not associated with .py files.  I decide to associate it with Notepad, then associate it with Python again.  That works the magic.  The icon is back, and so is the 'Edit with IDLE' option.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is arising because of the problem in the registry of Python installation. While one may edit the registry and resolve the issue, the simple solution for this can be:

1. **DELETE ALL THE REGISTRIES** pertaining to the py extensions and
2. **Re-install Python** and let installation take its course of action.

The problem will definitely resolve.

Happy Programming

Answer (score -1):

After uninstalling both `2.7` and `3.6`, reinstalling `3.6`, I ran the **init**.py ,**main**.py, and idle.pyw found in `C:\Program Files\python\Lib\idlelib` and the edit with menu reappeared