# Python Edit with IDLE + Sublime Text 3 issue

Tags: python, windows, sublimetext3, python-3.4, python-idle

Today suddenly 'Edit with IDLE' option is gone from context menu. I tried so many things on Regedit keys, not worked. So I downloaded Sublime Text.

First I couldn't even run `print("hello")` in sublime text, it threw `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`. I deleted Python and re-installed it.

That problem is still occuring, but right now I have another problem on Sublime text. I opened a script (that working perfectly without any error) with Sublime Text for editing. First of all, `input()` is not working. When I run the script on Sublime Text, I see input line but that's all. It's like Sublime Text prints only the input, not taking data or anything happens after then. I don't know why.

Second problem is, weirdly it raises `TabError` for **EVERY** line in the script.

[image]

As you see in the picture, `break` is excatly on the same line with `print` and `time.sleep()`. I tried everything and still no solution.

How can I fix this nonsense TabError?

How can I fix `input()` issue? (I downloaded sublimeRepl but it's not working, there is no option 'Edit with SublimeRepl' or else)

After all, why `Edit with IDLE` option is gone suddenly and not coming back?

I have tons of scripts and I can't even open a single one. I can't edit anything. Can't run anything.

Comment: the "why would the 'Edit with IDLE' option disappear" might be more relevent to http://superuser.com even though it is about a programming IDE it is about the program itself.

Comment: Try selecting the entire file and changing the indentation settings on the bottom-right from "Tab" to "4 spaces". Also, with "Edit in IDLE" context menu disappeared: have you run any registry cleaners/antivirus scans/system repair tools? If you re-run the Python installer and select "Reinstall", is it fixed?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Excatly I run a registry cleaner. I knew that was the problem. TabError is gone with your suggest, but `input()` problem is still here. I feel like you're the only one will solve my problem.

Comment: @GLHF Registry cleaners are almost *never* a good thing. Your `input()` issue is that [Sublime doesn't support input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604409/sublime-text-2-console-input).

Comment: And I'm pretty sure re-installing Python like I said will fix the context menu issue.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Yes then I searched for SublimeRepl but it doesn't work as expected. No I re-installed it, even I clean the reg keys of it. Still same.

Comment: What if you try [this](http://superuser.com/a/343565/217624) but replace the `27` in `Python27` with `34`?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Weirdly, that context menu issue is solved but not completely. I can edit some files but can't some files. I try to open that files with `Python Launcher for Windows` because it says this on that files I can edit. But when I search for that, computer can't find 'Python Launcher for Windows'.

Comment: Actually edit with IDLE works for only .pyw extension right now I understood that

Comment: Is there any pattern for where exactly it works? Or is it seemingly random? Also, are you *positive* you changed *all* the `27`s to `34`s? There's a reason I don't use Windows much anymore. ;)

Comment: Also, what's the output if you run `assoc .py` at a command promot window?

Comment: .py = Python.File this is the output

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos If you solve this problem when this question eligible for bounty in 2 days, I'll give you 200 bounty points. I'll freak out because of this nonsense problems.

Comment: @GLHF So "Edit with IDLE" still doesn't appear for `.py` files, but it does for `.pyw` files, correct?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Yes that's true.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely you have a mix of spaces and tabs. For Python I have a syntax specific Sublime-settings that shows whitespace characters `draw_white_space": "all",` so that these issues can be quickly seen. I also have it so that tabs are changed to spaces. My settings are below, feel free to modify as you wish:

```
{
    // editor options
    "draw_white_space": "all",

    // tabs and whitespace
    "auto_indent": true,
    "rulers": [79],
    "smart_indent": true,
    "tab_size": 4,
    "trim_automatic_white_space": true,
    "use_tab_stops": true,
    "word_wrap": true,
    "wrap_width": 80,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

As for the `Edit with IDLE` context missing, you may want to take a look at this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/343565/570687) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34321586/6061947) to see if you can add it back.

Comment: Where I should put these settings? Also it doesn't make any sense since all of them are on the same line, but only `break` raises error on that picture.

Comment: When you have a Python file open, you can go to `Preferences -> Settings - More -> Syntax Specific - User` and it should open a `Python.sublime-settings` file, where you can paste the above JSON. More information can be found about the options on [Sublime's unofficial documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/settings.html)