# Python -Edit with IDE doesn't show up on right click of any python file

Tags: python, windows

I have installed python version 2.7.Later updated with 3.4 and i was able to see  " Edit with IDE" option for python files.Due to project requirements  went back to 2.7.Later on, not able to see the "Edit with IDE option". Gone through some answers for the same issue and followed the steps as explained.But still i'm facing the same issue.Not sure if i'm doing any silly mistake.Please can any one help me to figure out the issue.[Snapshot of the Python installed location in Registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfUzC.png)

Comment: _"Gone through some answers for the same issue"_. Please provide a link to these answers so we don't waste your time suggesting the same solutions you already tried.

Comment: Which IDE were you using?

Comment: Below are the links  i have gone through http://superuser.com/questions/343519/python-idle-disappeared-from-the-right-click-context-menu

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179631/edit-with-idle-option-missing-from-context-menu

Comment: Right now the installed version is python 2.7

Comment: Where is python installed on your machine?

Comment: Make sure Python is configured to handle .py files. In the "open with" menu of a Python script, select "Choose another app". Select Python and enable "Always use this app to run .py files", and then click OK. This should enable the "Edit with IDLE" menu option that's configured for the `Python.File`  ProgId.